# Calculate the value of two different fields (int), and summarize those two into a new field in attribute table

Tags: arcmap, field-calculator, attribute-table, calculate-values

I am trying to make a pie chart, that means I have to connect some fields in AT.

How do I sum two integer fields into a new created field. The sum should also be connected to the different object id.

[image]

---

[image]

The picture show the type of calculation I have used, and the field `bef_0_4` and `bef_10_14` wont sum into the new `f14` field? Any clue of what has happened? The first row should sum into 70, but it calculated 62 after using the field calculator.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please be more specific which values you need summed up, and what you tried already. Also specify the software you're working with.

Comment: using arcmap, and trying to sum the two blue fields.  It worked now with using calculate field and sum those to the new created field

Answer (score 2):

To add a field click the triangle next to the table options button and select add field
[image]

specify the type as short or long integer (I believe the cut off for short is like 32,000 ish features, whie the long is 100,000ish)

[image]

Then right click the newly created column header and select field calculator.  There you can specify what Calculation you want to preform.  You can ignore the calculation outside of an edit session if you don't understand, just click yes and know that you won't be able to undo any calculations.

you can then build your calculation. eg

```
"BEF_0_4_ER" + "BEF_10_14"
```

Thats assuming you are using shapefiles

[image]

and Click ok to run and you should have a sum in your new field.

hope it helps

Comment: Hi, thank you for the help, When doing this the new field isnt calculated (11 + 20 = 31) but  with your guide I get this value in the new field = 1120. its just adding the value in both collums and not calculating the value, so that I can get a total population value. I want to get the value 31 (sum). Thanks for the help, I am  getting closer :D

Answer (score 0):

Solved, I had wrong data types: `string` instead of `int`.